# Have any cities (with a good economy) managed to prevent rapid increases in real estate costs?

Tags: city-planning, housing

Cities like London, Paris or Tel Aviv experience [frequent complaints](http://www.finchannel.com/business/realestate/64465-israel-housing-s-too-tight-to-mention) about the cost of real estate. Some blame [speculators](https://www.thestar.com/news/queenspark/2017/04/20/wynne-to-slap-15-per-cent-tax-on-foreign-real-estate-speculators.html), others blame [rich oligarchs](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/feb/04/mega-rich-homes-tour-london-oligarchs-russia-alexei-navalny-putin) from abroad, others say [not enough new buildings](http://gawker.com/san-francisco-nimbys-may-be-sacrificed-so-that-housing-1778151300) are being constructed, etc. There are numerous proposals on how to resolve the issue: [rent controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rent_control_in_New_York), high [taxes on vacant properties](http://www.cp24.com/news/city-may-tax-owners-of-estimated-65-000-vacant-homes-in-toronto-1.3347458), [allowing squatters](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2017/feb/24/serial-squatters-face-eviction-from-14m-london-mansion) to settle in empty buildings, [removing restrictions](http://www.bizjournals.com/sanfrancisco/blog/real-estate/2016/05/brown-affordable-housing-development-approval-ceqa.html) on height - all of them with significant trade-offs and from what I see few end up reducing the pressure on the market.

Have any well-off cities managed to keep real estate prices on a reasonable level? If so, how did they achieve it?

Comment: Define reasonsble.

Comment: @acpilot comparable to inflation levels

Comment: No because when you have growth the most desirable locations become more desired and people are willing to pay more to get it.  The prices go up because people are willing to pay those prices, If people refused to pay those prices then the prices would not be so high.

Comment: Under communism those market forces wouldn't be as strong and central planning may have created housing surpluses sometimes.

Comment: @SoylentGray and yet politicians like to talk about the 'outrageous' increases in rent/purchase prices and about how they're going to deal with it. I'm wondering if any of them have actually succeeded.

Comment: @JonathanReez - Yes tons of them get elected with those promises.  They are incredibly successful... ohh you meant in actually doing something..  There have been several socialism experiments.  None of them have been even close to successful though.

Comment: I think "reasonable" can be a synonym to "affordable housing" which seems to be when (rent value or installment amount) / income is less than 30% ([source](https://www.thepennyhoarder.com/smart-money/lower-housing-costs-affordable-small-towns/)).

Comment: Tokyo is the leading example. I'm make a proper post if I have time.

Comment: @ohwilleke You are right - Tokyo/Japan [seems to be](https://nsokolsky.substack.com/p/are-housing-prices-worse-than-ever?s=r) one of the very few places where real estate prices have been stable over the past 20 years, even with the Covid stimulus effect. Care to add an answer?

Comment: Land is just a limited resource. How shall a limited resource under ever greater demand be handled and differently than constantly rising in price?

Comment: @Trilarion [1 man = 1 property](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/are-there-countries-where-secondary-home-ownership-is-banned) could be a good start

Comment: @JonathanReez In the US the finger I usually see pointed is directed at zoning laws that enforce single family units (1 property for 1 man), as they prevent apartment complexes that could house more people on the same amount of land.  And housing more on the same amount seems the obvious solution to demand increasing and availability decreasing.  I think I read recently that Minneapolis has had success with getting rid of single family zoning, with it reducing rents while just about everywhere else rents are increasing.

Comment: I would refer to this https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/34249/if-rent-control-doesnt-work-and-supply-induces-demand-how-can-cities-improve/34268#34268 closely related question on the economics se and my answer to it. In short, Vienna, Austria seems to do a good job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tokyo, Japan](https://nsokolsky.substack.com/p/are-housing-prices-worse-than-ever?s=r) is one of the rare exceptions to this rule.

One of the primary reasons for this is that it has weak land use regulation, which allows for very high density real estate development, allowing more people to be housed on the same amount of land.

Politically, part of this is that land use regulation is handled at the national and regional level, rather than at the local level, which makes the interests of people considering moving to a locality in low housing prices, in addition to the interest of people who already own property there who have an economic interest in real estate price appreciation, more balanced. Regulating land use at a higher level means that regulators have a political interest in considering everyone's need, rather than only their local electoral base's interests.

In addition to a lack of direct regulation of density, Tokyo allows uses such as the following ones under its land use regulations, these allow:

- housing to lack parking (in a city that overall has very good public transit and intercity transit options, and is walkable and capable of being navigated by bike in lots of places, and in which there are a variety of strong deterrents to owning a car relative to the U.S. with European style expensive registration fees, difficult to obtain driver's licenses, and expensive gasoline, as well as limited supplies of parking due to land use policies);
- boarding houses in which rental residents share a kitchen and bathroom similar to a hostel (a fairly common source of housing for younger people, including minors studying a high schools or colleges far from home and people just starting out their working lives);
- housing without its own bathing facilities instead relying on residents using neighborhood bathhouses that are independent from the housing provider;
- residences with small minimum square footage;
- ultra tiny temporary residential facilities called pod hotels; and
- short term residential facilities called "love hotels" that can make the reduced privacy of living very close to your neighbors with thin walls tolerable.

A couple of other factors are not regulatory precisely, but are embedded practices that make a significant difference.

One is that many large Japanese businesses and some medium sized ones either offer lifetime employment or at least, have what I call "neo-feudal" practices in the sense that your business is not only your employer but provides employee benefits that account for a significant portion of your consumption, most notably, employer provided housing for many younger employees.

Another factor impacting land use is the way that Japanese cemeteries are operated. Basically, in an urban Japanese cemetery, you can't buy a burial plot or cremains storage shrine. Instead, you can only rent such spaces, and generally speaking, you can't pre-pay. If your next of kin doesn't pay the modest rental bill for the burial plot or public cremains storage box, the facility disposes of the remains as trash to make room for the remains of someone else whose family cares enough to pay the modest annual rental bill (and the bill gets bigger as you have more generations of remains to care for because there are more plots and current generations tend to be smaller than previous generations). This prevents land from being gobbled up by cemeteries in a way that is basically inalienable for residential development.

Yet another factor which both provides political motivations and influences the economics of housing, is that Japan, while it has significant income and asset inequality, like every capitalist country, has less income inequality than most Western countries do, which in turn, skews the incentives in the housing construction market less strongly towards the highest end housing.

Finally, housing demand in Tokyo is growing less intensely than many major cities due to a combination of factors:

- Japan as a whole has birth rates far below its death rates, with birth rates being lower in major cities just like almost every other developed country.
- Japan has little immigration, so it doesn't have a surge of foreign born people who need housing, driving demand.
- Japan's urbanization trend has come close to running its course. A large share of the formerly rural population that would have reason to move to a major city has already done so, so the pressure on housing demand from internal migration is not as intense as in countries that are in an earlier stage of urban migration. Some of this is due to physical geography, as much of Japan is mountainous and very expensive to develop high density housing upon as a result, so Japan's population has been concentrated in or near major urban centers that are suitable for this kind of development for a long time.

Comment: *This prevents land from being gobbled up by cemeteries in a way that is basically inalienable for residential development.* => this is an excellent point! Its crazy how much land in Western cities is taken up by cemeteries, often on prime downtown land.

Answer (score 7):

In Paris at least, the question could be reframed slightly. There have been periods of “housing crisis” (especially after the second World War) but not a continuous long-term increase in real estate prices (relative to everything else).

Specifically, between the 1960s and the early 2000s, prices (corrected for inflation) went up and down and never really got wildly out of sync with income. Growth and unemployment also had ups and downs but Paris was already a rich city with a flourishing economy. At the end of the 1990s, it was still conceivable that someone could buy real estate in Paris itself with income derived from an (upper) middle-class job (it was by no means open to everybody but still a perspective for many without being independently wealthy).

By contrast, since 2000, [real estate prices](https://www.immobilier-danger.com/Courbe-de-Friggit-024.html) have increased almost three-fold in Paris proper, two-fold in the broader Paris region relative to income. In fact they have also increased quite a bit in France in general (i.e. the increase is felt in large provincial cities too) but not as much. At the same time, the proportion of wealth that's inherited has also increased a lot, bringing France back to levels last seen in the 1930s (around 55%), after several decades where it was down to 20-30%.

All this suggests the complaints do not result only from the dynamics of the real estate market in a narrow sense but also from broader changes in the economy and the feeling that even a good job is not enough to own your own home or build up some wealth.

Comment: Excellent points, didn’t know about the inherited wealth thing.

Comment: What is the cost of real estate in Paris, vs the cost in other parts of France?

Comment: @jamesqf It's twice as expensive (per square meter, units tend to be smaller and older in Paris) as the next most expensive large city (Lyon), almost three times as expensive as even some fairly attractive cities like Nantes or Toulouse and 5 times as expensive as real estate in smaller or declining towns. Note that I am referring to the prices for Paris proper, which is tiny compared to many cities but the towns just next to it are almost as expensive.

Comment: If you follow the link, the red curve is Paris, pink is the broader Paris region, blue is everything outside of the Paris region, and the thin green curve is Lyon (but it's indexed on the prices in 2000 so not a good way to compare absolute prices).

Comment: @Relaxed: Then I can't help but wonder why people want to live in Paris, especially if salary differentials don't compensate for real estate price differences.  Especially these days, when many jobs can be done remotely.

Comment: @jamesqf Personally, that's exactly what I am doing at the moment but not that many jobs can actually be done remotely, especially in France (in my experience it was much easier to find German or US businesses willing to hire me fully remotely in France than a French company that didn't have a rule like at least 2 days a week at the office). There are towns like Rennes that promote themselves as a good place to live or even set up a business, even if you need to go to Paris regularly (1 hour high-speed train). I also know many people who switched careers for the sake of moving away from Paris.

Comment: If you care for a traditional career in government or in a blue chip company, you won't have many opportunities away from Paris (except maybe in the aerospace industry, which is centered in the south-west) and you won't progress if you're too far from the office. And then, there are all the service jobs from in education, healthcare, hospitality (half of all hospitality businesses in France are in Paris), cleaning, tourism, retail where you cannot work remotely. So all of this is happening but not at a scale that would threaten or counterbalance the weight Paris has in the French economy.

Comment: @jamesqf One last thing to note, I mentioned this already but Paris is tiny and the prices I mentioned are only about the municipality of Paris and the towns immediately surrounding it (*petite couronne*). What people do to either buy a house on a middle income or afford rent with a low-income job is move further and further away in the suburbs. So they work in Paris but do live elsewhere. Incidentally, the commute can be longer than the time it takes to reach cities like Nantes, Rennes or Lyon but it's cheaper.

Comment: @Relaxed "the commute can be longer" So you kind of pay with time instead. It's just an idea but if France would consist of many 1 million sized cities all connected by high speed train, people might be better off with lower rents and better access to nature and smaller commuting times.

Comment: @jamesqf Having lived in Paris I would say that if you can afford it, living in Paris is quite attractive in terms of general quality of life like food and culture. This might be similar in other big French cities but I don't have any personal experience there. In comparison, living in London is just a bad deal and living in other parts of the UK gives you a much better standard of living for a comparable income (also from personal experience).

Comment: @jamesqf Usually people live in these cities because even with the ridiculously high cost of living, the absolute amount of money you have to spend is higher (even if things are more expensive, it can be transferred back to places where it is cheaper) and also because they are good places to live other than the price problem.

Answer (score 6):

This is both a broad and interesting question. According to [Property Price Index](https://www.numbeo.com/property-investment/region_rankings.jsp?title=2017&region=150) 2017, London is indeed one of the most expensive when it comes to property prices and the most expensive in Europe.

Unfortunately, high prices have several root causes, making it hard to tackle this phenomenon ([source](http://www.economicshelp.org/blog/8733/housing/uk-house-prices-high/)):

> - **Growing demand** - [...] demand for housing has been rising at a faster rate than the supply.
> - **Constraints on the building of houses** - difficulty to find new land around greater London, preserving “greenbelt land”, existing
>   homeowners have a vested interest in keeping the supply as low as
>   possible in their area, lack of Social Housing
> - **strong demand for home ownership**
> - **Speculation**
> - **Low Interest rates**

There are several methods that can be used to cap the prices, most of them having some drawbacks ([source](http://www.economicshelp.org/blog/9140/economics/cap-house-prices-work/)):

> - **higher interest rates** - would have significant impact on reducing housing affordability, but might clash with controlling
>   inflation and economic growth
> - **mortgage regulation** - limiting the availability of mortgages through regulation. However, mortgage lending is already quite scarce.

The same article emphasizes that none of these measures attack the actual problem: disequilibrium of supply and demand. [This article](http://www.economicshelp.org/blog/7243/housing/housing-supply-in-uk/) dives into details about demand growing faster than supply.

Other methods that can be used are:

- **[price ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_ceiling)** - e.g.

**Apartment price control in Finland:**

> According to professors Niko Määttänen and Ari Hyytinen, price
> ceilings on Helsinki City Hitas apartments are economically highly
> inefficient. They cause queuing, and discriminate against the
> handicapped, single parents, elderly, and others not able to queue for
> days. They cause inefficient allocation, as apartments are not bought
> by those willing to pay the most for them—and those who get an
> apartment are unwilling to leave it, even when their family or work
> situation changes, since they can't sell it at what they feel the
> market price should be. These inefficiencies increase apartment
> shortage and raise the market price of other apartments.

**Rent control in New York City**

> The government put in price controls, so soldiers and their families
> could pay the rent and keep their homes. However, this increased the
> quantity demanded for apartments and lowered the quantity supplied,
> meaning that available apartments were rapidly taken until none were
> left for late-comers. Price ceilings create shortages when producers
> are allowed to abdicate market share or go unsubsidized.

- [Land value tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_value_tax#Real_estate_values) should work for lowering the rent, according to Wikipedia:

> At sufficiently high levels, land value tax would cause real estate
> prices to fall by removing land rents that would otherwise become
> 'capitalized" into the price of real estate

However, this kind of taxation is not very widespread:

> Land value taxation is currently implemented throughout Denmark,[7](http://www.verida.ro/index.php/2014/10/30/de-ce-vor-oamenii-sa-fie-proprietari/)
> Estonia, Lithuania,[8] Russia, Hong Kong, Singapore, and Taiwan; it
> has also been applied in subregions of Australia, Mexico (Mexicali),
> and the United States (e.g., Pennsylvania).

Keeping real estate prices at reasonable prices - e.g. Bucharest, Romania, place 48 in Europe's [price to income ratio](https://www.numbeo.com/property-investment/region_rankings.jsp?title=2017&region=150).

This is clearly not a "well-off city", but it can be used as a reference to what lead to reasonable prices for rents and housing:

- **fewer constraints on building houses** - most of the constructors built with few restrictions. This was a benefit for the consumers, but this rendered town planning almost useless and also reduced the green space
- **already existing high home ownership** - according to [this article](http://www.verida.ro/index.php/2014/10/30/de-ce-vor-oamenii-sa-fie-proprietari/) (Romanian), house ownership is more than 95% in Romania. So, supply should compensate only for the latecomers
- **much stricter mortgage regulation** - higher advanced value, lower warranty values, lower accepted debt/income value and other regulations lead to lower loaning
- **less State interference** - the Romanian Government ran a program called The First House which allowed banks to have less risk and lower the advance to only 5%. The programs conditions changed and the advance is more than 15% now, making loans harder to get.
- **context** - due to high ownership as opposed to renting and the fact that most of the owners are private individuals, in most cases they do not afford to keep the houses empty (due to fixed costs), so they lower the price to get a client faster).

**Note:** one comment talks about "socialism experiments". Romania has been under the Iron Curtain and thus had a communist regime until the end of 1989. House construction and prices were centrally controlled and almost everyone had a place to stay. Some argue that this was a "success". However, they forget that the largest houses and flats went to politicians, State Security members and informers.

Anyway, this was possible because **supply and demand were quite balanced**.

**Conclusion:** I don't think there is a sustainable way to prevent rising prices for real estate, as long as supply does not follow the demand.

Comment: Perhaps you could also take decentralization into account? E.g. Germany doesn't really have a 'mega-capital', as both their government and their industry is quite spread out around the country.

Comment: @JonathanReez - yes, that's an interesting aspect. I will try to improve the answer to include it.

Comment: @JonathanReez - I am trying to find some good articles about how decentralization helped Germany to keep reasonable prices, but it seems that they are facing the same problems, as seen [here](https://www.thelocal.de/20150819/germany-building-homes-in-wrong-places-experts) or [here](http://www.globalpropertyguide.com/Europe/germany/Price-History). I will have to dig more.

Comment: I think if the largest houses go to politicians, but everyone gets a house, that's still *significantly better* than the situation where (regardless of who the largest houses go to) not everyone gets a house.

Comment: Is there any evidence that lowering related taxes has ever lowered housing costs? Certainly every reduction in Stamp Duty in the UK has only increased housing costs as it adds fuel to the market. Equally reduction in interest rates and cheaper mortgage costs for landlords never seem to have a corresponding reduction in rents. So the Wikipedia sourced land tax idea seems a complete non-starter from my experience.

Comment: Yes, the answer is helpful but I would like to see arguments supported by data on prices/occupancy rates, etc. rather than quotes from economists. That's a lot more work than I'm willing to do though, so I can't complain.

Comment: One could add that in London specifically the situation is made much worse due to the structure of the available housing stock. London has a very small center with high rises (relative to its population) and the vast majority of the greater London area is covered with two story townhouses and free standing individual homes. Other major European cities have a much higher proportion of housing in apartment blocks with 4 or 5 floors or high rises.

Comment: Everyone having a place to stay sure sounds like a success compared to what we have today, even if there was some corruption involved.

Comment: "They cause queuing, and discriminate against the handicapped, single parents, elderly, and others not able to queue for days." - this, in particular, doesn't seem like a problem compared to the alternative (which is that those people don't even get a chance to have an apartment at all)

Answer (score 2):

Singapore is another unique and interesting case. [The *majority* of residents there live in public housing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_housing_in_Singapore), which means the government effectively determines the prices most people are paying for housing. I'm not able to find any comparable cases, but it is one way to solve the problem.